# Inserindo array de objetos em JSON no mysql com PHP

Tags: php, json

Boa tarde, pessoal.
Primeiro me perdoem se for uma dúvida muito ridícula, estou aprendendo a mexer com a linguagem ainda.
Eu tenho o seguinte json:

```
[
{
    "id": 0,
    "codigo": "847010",
    "valorTotal": 3652.44,
    "qtdTotal": 20,
    "descricao": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,",
    "produtos": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "nome": "Produto1",
            "preco": 100,
            "quantidade": 50,
            "totalParcial": 1826.22
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "preco": 100,
            "quantidade": 50,
            "totalParcial": 1826.22
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 1,
    "codigo": "010410",
    "valorTotal": 408.84000000000003,
    "qtdTotal": 6,
    "descricao": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,",
    "produtos": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "preco": 10,
            "quantidade": 2,
            "totalParcial": 136.28
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "preco": 10,
            "quantidade": 2,
            "totalParcial": 136.28
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "preco": 10,
            "quantidade": 2,
            "totalParcial": 136.28
        }
    ]
}
```

Gostaria de saber como percorrer este array e inseri-ló no mysql com php, estou usando o json_decode para transformar o JSON em array e fazendo um foreach para percorre-ló, precisaria que os produtos sejam inseridos com o código que os precede, cada produto é uma ROW na tabela produtos.
Alguém poderia me dar um exemplo, uma luz, por favor, estou batendo a cabeça com isto.

Comment: Parece estar no caminho certo - ou pelo menos funcional. Dentro do laço *foreach* você pode executar a SQL que insere os dados no banco. Que bando de dados está utilizando?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php) para converter o JSON para Array.

Exemplo:

```
$json = '[{
    "id": 0,
    "codigo": "847010",
    "valorTotal": 3652.44,
    "qtdTotal": 20,
    "descricao": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,",
    "produtos": [{
            "id": 0,
            "nome": "Produto1",
            "preco": 100,
            "quantidade": 50,
            "totalParcial": 1826.22
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "preco": 100,
            "quantidade": 50,
            "totalParcial": 1826.22
        }
    ]
}, {
    "id": 1,
    "codigo": "010410",
    "valorTotal": 408.84000000000003,
    "qtdTotal": 6,
    "descricao": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,",
    "produtos": [{
            "id": 2,
            "preco": 10,
            "quantidade": 2,
            "totalParcial": 136.28
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "preco": 10,
            "quantidade": 2,
            "totalParcial": 136.28
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "preco": 10,
            "quantidade": 2,
            "totalParcial": 136.28
        }
    ]
}]';

$json_para_array = json_decode($json, TRUE);

echo '<pre>'; // defini preformatacao
print_r($json_para_array); // imprime
```

Saída:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 0
            [codigo] => 847010
            [valorTotal] => 3652.44
            [qtdTotal] => 20
            [descricao] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
            [produtos] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 0
                            [nome] => Produto1
                            [preco] => 100
                            [quantidade] => 50
                            [totalParcial] => 1826.22
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [preco] => 100
                            [quantidade] => 50
                            [totalParcial] => 1826.22
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [codigo] => 010410
            [valorTotal] => 408.84
            [qtdTotal] => 6
            [descricao] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
            [produtos] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [preco] => 10
                            [quantidade] => 2
                            [totalParcial] => 136.28
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [preco] => 10
                            [quantidade] => 2
                            [totalParcial] => 136.28
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 4
                            [preco] => 10
                            [quantidade] => 2
                            [totalParcial] => 136.28
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

---

Para "trabalhar" o array, utilize um laço.

Exemplo:

```
foreach($json_para_array as $v) {

    echo 'id: ' . $v['id'] . ' codigo: ' . $v['codigo'] . '<br>';
}
```

Saída:

```
id: 0 codigo: 847010
id: 1 codigo: 010410
```

---

Com esses exemplos, praticamente terá que alterar dentro do seu laço, para gerar as queries e a inserção no banco.

Caso tenha dúvidas como gerar as queries, inserir, etc, aí seria outra pergunta, se não estaria ampla demais, e provavelmente seria fechada.

Teste essa parte básica, teste por fora como fazer um simples `insert`, depois é só juntar os 2!