# Como converter um Json para array PHP

Tags: php, json, array

Minha ideia é poder pegar cada elemento da meu `Json` e converter para `array` em `PHP`...

Esse é o `Json` que quero poder fazer `decode`, depois inserir cada elemento{true or false} dessa mesma string:

```
my string [{"aula":1,"disponibilidade":[{"disponivel":true},{"disponivel":true},{"disponivel":true},{"disponivel":true},{"disponivel":true}]},{"aula":2,"disponibilidade":[{"disponivel":true},{"disponivel":true},{"disponivel":true},{"disponivel":true},{"disponivel":true}]},{"aula":3,"disponibilidade":[{"disponivel":true},{"disponivel":true},{"disponivel":true},{"disponivel":true},{"disponivel":true}]},{"aula":4,"disponibilidade":[{"disponivel":true},{"disponivel":true},{"disponivel":true},{"disponivel":true},{"disponivel":true}]},{"aula":5,"disponibilidade":[{"disponivel":true},{"disponivel":true},{"disponivel":true},{"disponivel":true},{"disponivel":true}]}]
```

Json Formatado:

```
my string[  
   {  
      "aula":1,
      "disponibilidade":[  
         {  
            "disponivel":true
         },
         {  
            "disponivel":true
         },
         {  
            "disponivel":true
         },
         {  
            "disponivel":true
         },
         {  
            "disponivel":true
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "aula":2,
      "disponibilidade":[  
         {  
            "disponivel":true
         },
         {  
            "disponivel":true
         },
         {  
            "disponivel":true
         },
         {  
            "disponivel":true
         },
         {  
            "disponivel":true
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "aula":3,
      "disponibilidade":[  
         {  
            "disponivel":true
         },
         {  
            "disponivel":true
         },
         {  
            "disponivel":true
         },
         {  
            "disponivel":true
         },
         {  
            "disponivel":true
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "aula":4,
      "disponibilidade":[  
         {  
            "disponivel":true
         },
         {  
            "disponivel":true
         },
         {  
            "disponivel":true
         },
         {  
            "disponivel":true
         },
         {  
            "disponivel":true
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "aula":5,
      "disponibilidade":[  
         {  
            "disponivel":true
         },
         {  
            "disponivel":true
         },
         {  
            "disponivel":true
         },
         {  
            "disponivel":true
         },
         {  
            "disponivel":true
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Com o seguinte action:

```
<?php
require_once('../config/conexao.php');
require_once('../controllers/AbstractControle.php');
session_start();


$Turnos_idTurnos = addslashes($_REQUEST['turno']);
$Classe_idClasse = addslashes($_REQUEST['classe']);
$Professor_idProfessor = addslashes($_REQUEST['professor']);

//INSERT INTO `disponibilidade` (`idDisponibilidade`, `disponibilidade`, `Turnos_idTurnos`, `Professor_idProfessor`, `classe_idClasse`) VALUES (NULL, 'true', '1', '38', '1');
$array = array($disponibilidade, $Turnos_idTurnos,$Professor_idProfessor);

$sql = "INSERT INTO disponibilidade (disponibilidade, Turnos_idTurnos,Professor_idProfessor,classe_idClasse) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
$controle = new controle();
$con = $controle->salvar($array, $sql);

/*
$infor =json_decode($lista);
$presenca = $infor->
*/

echo json_encode();

?>
```

Comment: Apesar do título diferente a resposta serve: [Inserindo array de objetos em JSON no mysql com PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/318829/92908)

Comment: @rbz eu não acho que seja bem isso o que ele quer. Mas vou abster-me por enquanto.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento então é "não está clara o suficiente" 